# "Strange" inequality derived from continuity

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, epsilon-delta

Let $$ h(z):=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{i^{k+1}z^k}{(k+1)!} $$

$h$ is entire, so it is continuous. I saw the following argument [somehow] derived from continuity of $h(z)$:

> $\dots$ In particular, $h$ is continuous at $0$, so there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|z-0|<\delta$ implies $|h(z)|<2|h(0)|\dots$.

Here's how I would say:

In particular, $h$ is continuous at $0$, so there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|z-0|<\delta$ implies $|h(z)-h(0)|<\varepsilon$.

So that $h(0)-\varepsilon<h(z)<h(0)+\varepsilon$. Where's the $2$ before $|h(0)|$ coming from?

Comment: Is there more to the argument? By the way, this is a power series for $\frac{e^{ix} - 1}{x}$...

Comment: @BenjaminDickman No, nothing else to the argument.

Comment: What *is* $h(0)$? It requires evaluating either an expression with $0^0$ in the numerator, or, if you use the associated power series, evaluating an expression with $0$ in the denominator...

Comment: $ h(z):=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{i^{k+1}z^k}{(k+1)!} =i+i^2 z + i^3z^2/4+\dots $, so that $h(0)=i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|h(0)|=1 >0$

Hence by continuity, let $\epsilon = |h(0)|$,  $\exists \delta >0$ such that $|z-0| < \delta$ implies $$|h(z)-h(0)| < |h(0)|$$

Hence $|h(z)| = |h(z)-h(0)+h(0)| \leq |h(z)-h(0)| + |h(0)| < 2|h(0)|$